# UE4 difference between an Android game compiled with engine source code and a pre-compiled engine

Tags: android, build, unreal-engine4

The pre-compiled binary version of the engine is compiled using the same engine source code, but the `libUE4.so` in the build of the packaged Android apk is **15MB** larger than the one compiled using the source code, and only the `Shipping` version has this problem, the `Development` version is normal.

Does anyone know what is the reason for this?